# Node.js Global Dev Side Constant

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a global constant so that I can access them anywhere, i.e. server-side and client-side code.

Is there a module that makes this easy? I'm looking for Global Dev Side constants, meaning it does not need to change and in fact it would be great if I can compile my files to inject the variables inline when I need to go into production.

Comment: Global Dev Side? Is this some sort of term I am not familiar with? Regardless, you can't share JS memory between server and client without having some sort of transfer of data between the two.

Comment: It sounds like you want a macro preprocessor running over codebases of both server- and client-side js?

Comment: @Bergi I think you nailed it with the macro preprocessor. Know of any?

Comment: Not a particular one, but AFAIK basically every build tool uses/has one. Which build process do you use?

Comment: Create a global namespace in your main script and add all your global objects/variables to that namespace. You can also pass it to your client-side javascript using a template system such as ejs, jade etc.